# переменные в pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Хотелось бы в имени файла иметь версию компонентов, но только частично.

```
<version>1.${java.version}.${vaadin.version}.${buildNumber}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>21.0.6</vaadin.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
</properties>
```

т.е. из переменной `<vaadin.version>21.0.6</vaadin.version>` взять только 21, что бы получилось 1.8.21.1, а не 1.8.21.0.6.1

Comment: Для чего Вам это нужно?

Comment: Просто если вы хотите это сделать для того, чтобы потом использовать в контроллере данную версию, то это можно сделать другими путями

Comment: А если Вам конкретно нужно просто изменить данный параметр в pom.xml, то это другой вопрос. Обычными средствами это нельзя сделать